# Array index return null instead of out of bound

Tags: c#, .net, properties, indexing

I am currently trying to implement an "indexed" property within my class definition.

For example I have the following class:

```
public class TestClass
{
   private int[] ids = null;

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public int[] Ids { 
      get
      {
         //Do some magic and return an array of ints 
         //(count = 5 - in this example in real its not fixed)
         return _ids;
      }
   }
}
```

Now I like to use this class as the following:

```
private void DoSomething()
{
   var testClass = GetSomeTestClass();
   //work with the ids

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //I know I could say i < Ids.Length, its just an example
   {
      int? id = testClass.Ids[i];
      //this will result, in a out of bound exception when i reaches 5 but I wish for it to return a null like a "safe" index call ?!?
   }
}
```

So is there a safe index call that results in a null, without the need for me to wrap it again and again in a try catch.

Another thing I dont wish to use the class index, because I need several properties that work like this, with different types (int, string, bool, custom class and so on).

(Again the for is just a simple example, I know I could in this case say "i < Ids.Length")

Comment: It's easy enough to write code that behaves like this, but you should question your motives. *All* sane data structures give you ways to determine if an indexed access is legal without resorting to `try/catch`. Why do you want to roll your own "out of bounds handling" instead of using the existing facilities?

Comment: After typing the 100th if statement checking if its in the bound, I gone tired of it and wanted to ask if something like this is possible. I know its not a standard behaviour, but maybe there was a way to do it I thought. Maybe a static extension or something, I dont know.

Comment: You got tired of it and decided to check if the result is `null` instead? Is that an improvement somehow?

Comment: Not really, because in my app I dont care if its null or an int. I just want to pass an array item to a nullable type variable, there "was" an extension method some secs ago in the answer that was enough for me, but it got deleted. :(

Comment: @RandRandom I removed my answer because you can't use `T` as `Nullable<T>` parameter unfortunately. I am working on an alternative though...

Comment: @RandRandom: I sincerely believe that you are fixating not on an actual problem but on how to make a proposed solution work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, whole new approach. Since you have several possible types and want a "joker" method, you can store the values as key/value collection in your class then such method becomes possible.

First, to store the values internally:

```
public class TestClass
{
     private Dictionary<Type, Array> _values = new Dictionary<Type, Array>();
}
```

Now to populate that collection with actual data:

```
_values.Add(typeof(int?), new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
_values.Add(typeof(string), new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" });
```

And finally the joker method:

```
public T Get<T>(int index)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    Array array;
    if (_values.TryGetValue(type, out array))
    {
        if (index >= 0 && index < array.Length)
        {
            return (T)array.GetValue(index);
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Usage:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  int? id = testClass.Get<int?>(i);
  string name = testClass.Get<string>(i);
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you were only interested in already non-nullable type data e.g. `struct` you could have gotten away with a simple extension method e.g.

```
public static class ArrayExt
{
    public static Nullable<T> GetValueOrNull(this T[] array, int index) where T: struct
    {
        return array.Length < index ? new Nullable<T>(array[index]) : null;
    }
}
```

which would have allowed you to simply call

```
int? id = testClass.Ids.GetValueOrNull(i);
```

However, given you need to support an arbitrary number of types my suggestion would be to implement a wrapper around an array and take control over how you access the data e.g.

```
public class SafeArray<T>
{
    private T[] items;

    public SafeArray(int capacity)
    {
        items = new T[capacity];
    }

    public object this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return index < items.Length ? (object)items[index] : null;
        }
        set
        {
            items[index] = (T)value;
        }
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass()
    {
        Ids = new SafeArray<int>(5);
        Instances = new SafeArray<MyClass>(5);
    }
    ...
    public SafeArray<int> Ids { get; private set; }

    public SafeArray<MyClass> Instances { get; private set; }
}
```

The key to this approach is to use `object` as the return type. This allows you to cast (or box/unbox if using value types) the data to the expected type on the receiving end e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // we need an explicit cast to un-box value types
    var id = (int?)testClass.Ids[i];
    // any class is already of type object so we don't need a cast
    // however, if we want to cast to original type we can use explicit variable declarations e.g.
    MyClass instance = testClass.Instances[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's really not much else you can do here than just:

```
if (i >= array.Length) return null;
else return array[i];
```

or, using the `?` operator:

```
return (i >= array.Length) ? null : array[i];
```

Comment: But the problem I have with this, I would need to again and again ask for this - isnt there a way to "extend" the index behaviour that it always works like this?

Answer (score 1):

1. from what I have read I see you are implemet a property of an array type, but not an indexer
2. it is kind of a moveton to fake index out of range situation and it would be still much much better if you take in your code care about out of range. at the end of the day nobody prevent you on assigning a default (in your case NULL) value when range is violated

if you need a shortcut for your the situation you have described above, I would go for the following method in your class:

```
 public int? ReadAtOrNull(int index)
{
  return index < ids.Lenght && index > 0 ? (int?)ids[index] : null;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use method instead of property:

```
public int? Ids(int i) {
    if (i >= 0 && i < _ids.length)
    {
        return _ids[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

People may start complaining that this may be an overhead, but what if you used `Skip` and `FirstOrDefault`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //I know I could say i < Ids.Length, its just an example
{
   int? id = testClass.Ids.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Mind you that in this case you may need to declare your array as `int?[]` otherwise the default value is `0` instead of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

please Try :

```
for (int i = 0; i <  Ids.Length; i++) 
   {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(testClass.Ids[i].Tostring()) 
      int? id = testClass.Ids[i];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the think to do here is to use a class index. Here is a direct answer for your `TestClass` example.

You could also derive your own custom collection class strictly for Ids that stores an int[] internally and overrides all the appropriate access calls I.e) Add, Remove, etc.. (and index the collection like this to make using it easier). Then you could have a property named `Ids` in your `TestClass` that behaves like the example.

I know this question is 3 months old but I hope this still helps.

```
public class TestClass {

    private int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int? this[int index] {
        get {
            if (index < 0 || index > ids.Length - 1)
                return null;

            return ids[index];
        }
        set {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(
                    "this[index]", 
                    "Ids are not nullable"
                );

            ids[index] = (int)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    private void DoSomething() {
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int? id = testClass[i];
        }

        // You can assign to the Ids as well
        testClass[0] = 6;
    }
```